# Meaning of "to risk, in turn, a woman's paradox"

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-barrett-browning, aurora-leigh

From *Aurora Leigh*:

> To have our books
>   Appraised by love, associated with love,
>   While we sit loveless! is it hard, you think?
>   At least 'tis mournful. Fame, indeed, 'twas said,
>   Means simply love. It was a man said that.
>   And then there's love and love: the love of all
>   (**To risk, in turn, a woman's paradox,**)
>   Is but a small thing to the love of one.
>   You bid a hungry child be satisfied
>   With a heritage of many corn-fields: nay,
>   He says he's hungry,–he would rather have
>   That little barley-cake you keep from him
>   While reckoning up his harvests. So with us;
>   (Here, Romney, too, we fail to generalise!)
>   We're hungry.

I wonder what the meaning of the phrase in bold could be. It must be an allusion to some paradox or some story, or some saying, mustn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* says:

> **paradox**, *n.* **2. a.** An apparently absurd or self-contradictory statement or proposition, or a strongly counter-intuitive one, which investigation, analysis, or explanation may nevertheless prove to be well-founded or true.

The paradox in this case is in the surrounding lines:

> the love of all […] Is but a small thing to the love of one.

This is counter-intuitive because *all* would seem to be greater than *one*. But in context *the love of all* refers to the adulation of readers for a famous writer:

> To have our books Appraised by love […] Fame, indeed, 'twas said, Means simply love.

while *the love of one* refers to the love of a child for his mother (hence a *woman's* paradox).